# Is it possible to categorize or split the nouns, pronoun and adjective data in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Here's my sample data from my dataset and if anyone can help me to fix this problem i want to get the nouns and adjectives from a sentence. If this possible is there anytutorial or link to study this kind of problem or someone can help me. I want to separate all noun, pronoun and adjective words. I already tried the excel formula to find specific word but it is not recommendable because what i want to get all of the possible noun, pronoun and adjective word not given. thankyou!

[image: Sample output]

Comment: I may be wrong with this, but unless you add a list with all possible nouns , pronouns and adjectives (Yes, all of them), excel will not understand what matches your criteria. Unless you can code an AI and teach it to identify the language.

Comment: Is this homework as someone else has asked today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036428/extracting-the-noun-adjective-words-in-excel-vba  EXACTLY!

Comment: You will have to compile a dictionary of all noun's and adjectives you want to find and also decided whether they need to be compared to the base of the word. You will then need to compare against this list to see if there are any results

Comment: i havent seen this but this post was posted by my member we're developing right now a excel based guidance system the objective is to find the possible reasons why the students always leaves or drops there subject or leaving the school. We conducted an interview and we gathered 500 rows and we already coded the interview form and already saving to the database storage but the problem is how to get the noun and adjectives like shown in the link sorry sir i am php programmer and vba is new to me sorry sir again

Comment: You will need to define which words are nouns and which are adjectives and also analyse the context to catch those words that can be used as either as a noun or as an adjective.

Comment: Your opinion guys are very helpful for us. As of now we coded the split text where all of the sentence were splitted and we're planning to count most used words in the data set and we will also consider your opinion guys.

Comment: It sounds less like you are collecting lists of adjectives and nouns and more like you're collecting a set of "reasons" (the word "reason" is also a noun, yet it's not included in your NOUN column). It sounds like what you need is an enumerated list of potential reasons, with an "Other, please specify" option, that a person would fill out. There'd probably be some manual work involved in this as well, and moreso if you've already collected all of your data, but it could be made to be quite quick in various ways, e.g., data validation, Excel's built in auto-complete. Just my thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

It will require a reference list, but it can be done by formula not VBA, for example.

[image]

Using the **array** formula as follows

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($A$2:$A$4,$C2,1))),ROW($A$2:$A$4)),COLUMN(D1)-3),1)`

in D2 to F4.